# the domain and range of $g(x) = f(6x-4)+8$ when $f(x)$ has a domain: $\{-3,-1,0,2\}$ and range: $\{2,5,7\}$

Tags: functions

As the title says, I am trying to find the domain and range of $g(x) = f(6x-4)+8$ when $f(x)$ has a domain: $\{-3,-1,0,2\}$ and range: $\{2,5,7\}$

What would/how do you find the domain of $g(x)$? and the range of $g(x)$? using $f(x)$'s domain and range, as well as the formula $g(x)=f(6x-4)+8$

Comment: What if we apply $10$ to $g$, would there be any problem?$g(10)=???$

Comment: yes, that's a problem, since you're only allowed to use g's domain. the problem is, I'm not sure what g(x)'s domain actually is... that's one part of the problem--finding out g(x)'s domain from the information given by f(x). After that part is done, then there's the second part of finding g(x)'s range using g(x)'s domain.

Comment: $g(10)=f(6 \times 10 -4)+8$, Do you see any problem?

Comment: But why can't you do $g(10)$? Perhaps that will show which numbers *are* in the domain.

Comment: If I want to apply $10$ to $g$, I must be able to apply $56$ to $f$, but can I do that?

Comment: Oh, you may be right, but what I was thinking was that I had to use f(x)'s range to create g(x)'s domain. For example, using any number from the set {2,5,7} and doing something with that to create g(x)'s domain. I might have been wrong? But I said that was a problem because if we used 10 how would that connect to f(x) at all? then the domain of g(x) would be all real numbers, which is definitely incorrect

Comment: @hhsaffar, no, the domain of f is only the set of elements {-3,-1,0,2}. since 56 isn't in the domain of f it won't work. that's what I was mentioning in the comment i just made.

Comment: So if $x$ wants to be in the domain of $g$, then $6x-4$ must be in the domain of $f$, isn't it?

Comment: yes, that's correct. 6x-4 must be in the domain of f.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $f(6x-4)+8$ to be defined, the argument of $f$ should only take values $-3,-1,0,2$. Equating $6x-4$ to these numbers, gives $x$ equal to $\frac16, \frac12, \frac23$ and $1$. Hence these are the only values that $x$ can take and thus, this is the domain of $g$.

Since $f(6x-4)$ evaluates to $2,5$ and $7$ only, the range of $g$ can be found by substituting these values for $f(6x-4)$ in the expression $f(6x-4)+8$. Thus, the range is $\{10, 13,15\}$.

Comment: thank you so much! question though, slightly confused as to how you got to the fractions as the domain of g. from what values did you get those numbers?

Comment: nevermind. i got it, you set the 6x-4 equal to the elements in f(x)'s domain. thank you so much for your help!

Comment: @gticecream8 You're welcome. Basically, we need to find values of $x$ such that the function $g$ given by $g(x)=f(6x-4)+8$ is defined. Since the domain $f$ is $\{-3,-1,0,2\}$, these values of $x$ should be such that $6x-4$ evaluates to one of $-3,-1,0,2$. These can be found by equating $6x-4$ to these numbers.

Comment: if you have time/interest, could you help with a similar problem? only if you're interested! it's using the same codomain/domain,but involves absolute value. it's not the same problem. http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/586494/giving-the-domain-and-range-of-an-equation-includes-absolute-value-of-fx-n